# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Tags: asp.net

I was facing this issue, I tried all the things but was unable to resolve the problem.

My Solution:

On checking I found that assembly was added in GAC. It was creating problem.

I just removed the assembly from GAC, it started working. Happy Coding.

Comment: Please give your solution as a separate answer. There is no problem with answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

On checking I found that assembly was added in GAC. It was creating problem.

I just removed the assembly from GAC, it started working. Happy Coding.